# SPARK_HOME read from IntellIj IDEA

Tags: apache-spark, intellij-idea, hive

I know it might be trivial question, but I stuck with it for a while :) Basically, I am querying Hive tables from Spark. All connections settings for Hive I have in hive-site.xml file which is in SPARK_HOME/conf directory on my Windows PC. It works fine through spark-shell. However, when I run the same from IntelliJ Idea, it will query Hive locally instead connecting to remote metastore defined in hive-site.xml.

```
package main.scala

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object Main {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("Hive Tables")
      .master("local")
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.sql
    sql("show tables").show()
  }
}
```

I have added environmental variables for HADOOP_HOME and SPARK_HOME. As I mentioned it works fine through spark-shell. But seems like hive-site.xml is not read in IntelliJ Idea.

Do you have any ideas what I may do wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: `spark-shell` is a shell script that invokes other shell scripts that set up a bunch of environment variables, incl. CLASSPATH, plus a bunch of command-line args for the Spark launcher (which then bootstraps the driver, etc) -- it does a **lot** under the covers.

Comment: Try to add explicitly `%SPARK_HOME%/conf` (yes, the directory) to the CLASSPATH. That way, the Hadoop libs will search that dir for all `*-site.xml` conf files.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter, thanks that was actually the solution. Basically, I had to go to Project Structure-->Modules, and there I found out that resource folder is \src\main\resources. I just copied hive-site.xml there. And works ! Thanks :)